# How can i display the posts per week in a particular month?

Tags: php, wordpress

*I have to display the posts as the following*

**September 2010**

*Friday September 24, 2010*

```
post1
post2
.
.
.
```

*Friday September 17, 2010*

```
post1
post2
.
.
.
```

*Friday September 10, 2010*

```
post1
post2
.
.
.
```

*Friday September 03, 2010*

```
post1
post2
.
.
.
```

**can any one tell, how can do this?, or which function should i use?**

I have used the following function and i got all the post in current month

```
query_posts("year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month")
```

How can i show the posts per week of this month?

**is it work** `query_posts(""year=$current_year&monthnum=$current_month&post_date >$startDate&post_date <=$endDate")`

**Or what is another good way?**

Comment: You probably want to ask this on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

So this is actually very simple, all you need to do is print the week heading every time the week changes. If you want this to happen every Friday, just have something like this in the loop inside the while statement:

```
<?php
if(get_the_time("N")==5):
?>
<h1><?php the_time(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You'll need some logic to determine if the first post is not a Friday, and compensate for the difference. But this is pretty close I think.